# SQL Query that pulls rows in current table based on parent id optimization

Tags: optimization, performance, mysql, sql

I am creating a user permission system. I will have my user permissions set up off of "objects" and not pages. For example, I have an `EVENTS` section. Within that section, there are `FORMS`, `FEES`, etc. I want to be able to handle permissions down to the child levels.

Here is my permission_objects table:

```
| id | object | parent_id |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | EVENTS | NULL      |
| 2  | FORMS  | 1         |
| 3  | FEES   | 1         |
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT `up`.*
FROM `permission_objects` `po`
INNER JOIN `user_permissions` `up` ON `up`.`object`=`po`.`id` AND (`up`.`user_group`=2 OR `up`.`user_id`=17)
WHERE `po`.`object`='EVENTS' OR `po`.`parent_id`=(
  SELECT `id` FROM `permission_objects` WHERE `object`='EVENTS'
)
```

I really want to avoid doing a subquery. I thought that instead of having a `parent_id` I could have `parent_object` and have that contain the parent's object value. i.e. `| 2 | FORMS | EVENTS |`. That way I could change my `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE `po`.`object`='EVENTS' OR `po`.`parent_object`='EVENTS'
```

However I feel that keeping it as `parent_id` is a better approach. Is there a way to keep that but not have to have a subquery in my sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub-query as a concept is not a problem... you need to do that work, and this is a decent way to do it.

It would be better if it was expressed as a direct lookup... like:

```
WHERE `po`.`object`='EVENTS'
   OR exists (
      SELECT `sub`.`id`
      FROM `permission_objects` `sub`
      WHERE `sub`.`object`='EVENTS'
        and `sub`.`id` = `po`.`parent_id`
)
```

This sub-select is better because it can do an indexed lookup in the table in the sub-select based on the `id` column.

Apart from that, I don't see a better, or neater way to do it.

Comment: Did you mean `and sub.id = po.parent_id`?

Comment: @Aust Yes, I did ;-)

Comment: I thought so but I've never seen `exists` so I wasn't exactly sure. =) I do have one question though, how does `exists` compare to adding `LEFT JOIN permission_objects po2 ON po2.parent_id=po.id` and changing `... up ON (up.object=po.id OR up.object=po2.id) ...`

Comment: The left-join wont give you what you want because you need the OR condition on the parent's Event..... and that will produce duplicate results. `exists` is the right tool for this job. You **do** have an index on the permission_objects.id column, right?

Comment: Yes I have my id columns indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Your query probably doesn't do what you intend, because `AND` has higher precedence that `OR`.  It is therefore equivalent to

```
SELECT `up`.*
    FROM `permission_objects` `po`
        INNER JOIN `user_permissions` `up`
            ON (`up`.`object`=`po`.`id` AND `up`.`user_group`=2)
            OR `up`.`user_id`=17
    WHERE `po`.`object`='EVENTS'
        OR `po`.`parent_id`=(
            SELECT `id` FROM `permission_objects` WHERE `object`='EVENTS'
        )
```

You probably meant

```
SELECT `up`.*
    FROM `permission_objects` `po`
        INNER JOIN `user_permissions` `up`
            ON `up`.`object`=`po`.`id`
            AND (`up`.`user_group`=2 OR `up`.`user_id`=17)
    WHERE `po`.`object`='EVENTS'
        OR `po`.`parent_id`=(
            SELECT `id` FROM `permission_objects` WHERE `object`='EVENTS'
        )
```

However, that's not really a join condition.  I'd move the `user_group` and `user_id` filter to the `WHERE` clause.  Since you are interested in the `user_permissions` more than the `permission_objects`, I'd make `user_permissions` the primary table.

```
SELECT `up`.*
    FROM `user_permissions` `up`
        INNER JOIN `permission_objects` `po`
            ON `up`.`object` = `po`.`id`
    WHERE
        (`up`.`user_group` = 2 OR `up`.`user_id` = 17)
        AND (
            `po`.`object`='EVENTS'
             OR `po`.`parent_id`=(
                 SELECT `id` FROM `permission_objects` WHERE `object`='EVENTS'
             )
         )
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I meant to put that OR in (). Oops! ... Are there performance gains from using user_permissions as the primary table instead of permission_objects?

Comment: Using `user_permissions` as the primary table is a stylistic change; performance should be the same.